# ListView with custom view type build from a list of ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a list view along with an observable collection of view models. Each view model is designed to work with a view.

Is there a way to bind the ListViews ItemsSource to the observable collection of view models and have it just 'know' to create the views and bind them to the view models in the collection?

I've seen some things with DataTemplate but that seems to be more if you want to embed the view itself into the list view declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemTemplate` of an `ItemsControl` defines how each item in the `ItemsSource` collection is presented on the screen.

You should set it to a `DataTemplate` that contains your view:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- This template will be applied to each item in "YourCollection": -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Data Templating Overview:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have a similar situation but I don't know how i get/access the individual `item` from `YourCollection` in my `MyViewViewModel`. The `MyView` in my case expects a `public RJob job` so i need to set in somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out using:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
        <local:MyView />
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I didn't think it was working because the live data binding didn't produce a list of 'MyView', looks like the issue is with the live data binding then :)

Comment: You should set the ItemTemplate to a DataTemplate. Please refer to my answer for more information.